# How to cast a apache spark column to an array in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a statement to split the values of the column which contains email ids w.r.t '@' :

```
split(col("Email_Address"),"@").as("User_Id")
```

For an email id `test@gmail.com`, the above statement returns the dataset as `["test","gmail.com"]`.

Apache Spark java doc says split function returns 'column'.

How do I convert column to an array or a list so that I can extract only the string that comes before the '@'?

I tried to use cast function :

```
split(col("Email_Address"),"@").cast("String[]")[0].as("User_Id")
```

But this did not cast it into an array.

Comment: Why not do the split in Java? Just read the entire value as a string and use the `String#split()` method in your code.

Comment: doesn't doing `split(col("Email_Address"),"@")[0].as("User_Id")` helped?

Comment: Doing split(col("Email_Address"),"@")[0] did not work because split method returns a column and it complains that "Expected is array but found column"

Comment: @JimGarrison I tried this as you suggested : List<Row> rowsList = new ArrayList<Row>();
        rowsList = inputDataset.collectAsList();. Then I iterated through the list to get the email address as string and split it and it worked. Now I am trying to figure out how to add the split string value to a new column. Thanks!!

Comment: you should try udf function then